# How to get particular key values in an array using javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Tried to get particular key value from an nested array object but not working.In my code from an nested array trying to get parent key value and push to an new array.How to get it?

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xgxmfp?file=src/app/app.component.ts

app.component.ts:

```
      this.getReport$.forEach((element,index)=>{
              this.arr.push(element.ordered); 
      });

      this.arr.forEach((element,index)=>{ 
              this.parents.push(element[index].parent); 
      });

      console.log(this.parents);
```

Comment: Can you please also share the input array and the expected final result array?

Comment: Do you want extract your `object` key-value into new array ?

Comment: What exacly you need here? your question is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: make change in html file as shown in imag]

> you have to use concat in place of push

```
      this.arr.forEach((element,index)=>{ 
             // this.parents.push(element[index].parent); 
 this.parents= this.parents.concat(element)
      });

      console.log(this.parents);


   //  ngOnInit() {
  //   let me=this
  //   this.getReport$.forEach((element, index) => {
  //     this.arr.push(element.ordered);
  //   });
  //   let dataPrepare = [];
  //   this.arr.forEach((element, index) => {
  //     debugger
  //     this.getReport$[index].date;
  //     element.forEach((element2, index2) => {  
  //       debugger     
  //       element2.date= me.getReport$[index].date;
  //      // dataPrepare = dataPrepare.concat(element);
  //     });

  //     dataPrepare = dataPrepare.concat(element);
  //   });
  //   var objectTracker = new Map();
  //   let tempdataPrepare = dataPrepare.map((element, index) => {
  //     if (objectTracker.has(element.itemid)) {
  //       let tempEle = objectTracker.get(element.itemid);
  //       element.total = element.total + tempEle.total;
  //       element.qty = element.qty + tempEle.qty;
  //       this.totalSoldProduce = this.totalSoldProduce - tempEle.total;
  //       objectTracker.delete(element.itemid);
  //       objectTracker.set(element.itemid, element);
  //       this.totalSoldProduce = this.totalSoldProduce + element.total;
  //     } else {
  //       let id = element.itemid;
  //       objectTracker.set(element.itemid, element);
  //       this.totalSoldProduce = this.totalSoldProduce + element.total;
  //     }
  //   });
  //   this.parents = Array.from(objectTracker.values());
  //   console.log(this.parents);
  //   console.log(this.totalSoldProduce);
  // }
```

Comment: See Tea is duplicate..Coming two times.So can you add Tea's qty and total? example Tea's Total Qty  = 8 bcoz (4+3) same Tea's Sold Total = 1500 Bcoz (1250+250)

Comment: Is it possible?

Comment: I am Waiting for your reply

Comment: i written some commented code as per your requirement, replace this with your ngOnInit

Comment: How we can show all total?

Comment: added one variable totalSoldProduce,  also made change on ngOninit, you need to  bind totalSoldProduce in ui

Comment: Not working : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cjl1vj?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: initialize this.totalSoldProduce=0; starting of Oninit, now this should work

Comment: Finally i have one request..Can we show the date on each product..each ordered have one date. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pheonq?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: i made required change in commented onInit code, please check